# PCA- Display the projected image onto the principal components

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pca, eigenvector

I projected the 32*32 image data ([eigenface](https://github.com/kaleko/CourseraML/blob/master/ex7/data/ex7faces.mat)) onto the principal components using below function.

```
def projectData(X, U, K):
    # Compute the projection of the data using only the top K eigenvectors in U (first K columns).
    # X: data
    # U: Eigenvectors
    # K: your choice of dimension
    new_U = U[:,:K]
    return X.dot(new_U)
```

Let's say my K is 10. Now I have 100-dimensional data instead of 1024 (32*32). 
When I display the data I got below image.

[image]

Is this normal behavior? 
I'm following Andrew NG's ML class for PCA (https://github.com/kaleko/CourseraML/blob/master/ex7/ex7.ipynb) and noticed no tutorials in that class display the p**rojected data itself**, but they always display the **reconstructed version** (recover the data by projecting them back onto the original high dimensional space, then display)

My question is:
How should I display the projected data? Is it even meaningful to display the projected data itself? Why do all other tutorials recover the data and then display?

Comment: When you reconstruct the face using the 100-dimensional descriptor you are demonstrating that the projection successfully (or unsuccessfully) encodes enough information to identify the individual. If the reconstructed face doesn't look like the same person then there's probably not enough information being encoded to perform facial recognition.

Comment: @jodag Hi, thank you for your comment. The thing is when I displayed first 10 eigenvectors, it is able to display the faces pretty well only by using 10 eigen vectors. But when I display the dataset which is dot-producted (therefore projected on PC) with eigenvectors, I don't get any faceshape. So I was wondering I might not fully understand the concept of the projection here.